# What does <app-register> mean in Angular?

Tags: angular

I'm working on an Angular 8 and asp.net core app and I'm very new to Angular. I've made some components, a component for login and one for the register and one for home, etc. But I don't understand the purpose of using app-register inside my home.component.html. The following are code inside my home.component.html file.

```
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div style="text-align: center">
    <h1>Find your match!</h1>
    <p class="lead">All you need to do is sign up!!</p>
    <div class="text-center">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mr-2">Register</button>
      <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Info</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
     <div class="row justify-content-center">
       <div class="col-4">
         <app-register></app-register>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when it comes to angular every page you design we call it as a component for example

(***if your application has login Register and home page we call it as Login component and Register component and Home Component...*** )

and also like if you create an angular project you will have `app.componet.html`  which is the default component loaded when the application starts so if you want some other component to be included in the `app.componet.html` then you can add that component in the HTML file.

**How you can add it ??**

you can open any of the component ts file.. for example I will take `news.componet.ts` in that you can see

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-news',
  templateUrl: './news.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./news.component.css']
})
```

here you can see **selector**  tag using that you can include any  component to your HTML page.

like `<app-news></app-news>`

I hope I have answered your questions..

Answer (score 0):

in angular you have three file like `home.component.html` `home.component.ts` `home.component.scss`in the `home.component.ts` you can connect angular with back-end(.net)
for example you use rest API send some `.json`

Comment: anytime @Neyamat